# Viewing TF2 server-side replay blocks

Tags: team-fortress-2

I'm sure another TF2 admin has tried to view the replay files stored on his server, to investigate a cheater. But I can't figure out how to do that myself or find any instructions about it. Isn't it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?
**http://didrole.com/Replay2Demo/**

OMG it just works! You open the demo player in tf2 with shift-F2 an load the demo. Press shift-F2 again to regain camera control.

and stop answering your own questions, stupid.